# Deploy Manifest project using MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, manifest, office-addins, msdeploy

I want to automate build/publish process of my office addin. For web project I can use MSbuild to build and publish project with user interaction. I need similar solution for Manifest project, but I am unable to find one. Is there any way to automate publish process for Office addin manifest project? Or can I set path of output folder to some location at my system instead of \bin\Release\app.publish\OfficeAppManifests\ location.

**Edit:**

When publishing Addin Manifest project, it asks for website url as shown in image below. In case of adding post build event, how can I pass this as parameter when running MSbuild/MSdeploy command? [image: Publish Dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the post-build event to copy the file programmatically wherever you need:

[image: the post-build event in visual studio]

Comment: any idea how to add website url parameter as visual studio asks it on publish or I will have to keep different copies of manifest file for each url.

Comment: You can use the `copy` command to copy the source manifest and then process it by using a custom utility (executable) which can edit the manifest according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `move "$(ProjectDir)bin" "destination folder path"` in post build event.

Comment: can I get MSbuild parameter here as destination folder can be specified as PublishDir, OutDir etc. Also When we publish addin manifest project it asks for website url, how to provide it here?

Comment: How is the console application related to the web add-in? :)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I'll delete the screenshot, the focus is on the command line in post build event.

Comment: In your code you are moving the `bin` folder to a destination folder, not the manifest file.